# conjugacy classes of a matrix satisfies an equation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I met with a linear algebra problem which ask me to describe all conjugacy classes of $6\times6$ matrices $A$ which satisfy the equation $(A+1)^2(A-1)^4=0$.

Since I am not very familiar with abstract algebra, I think I do not quite understand the conjugacy classes(for a matrix).

I searched the definition, and in abstract algebra, conjugate classes of $a$ in a group $G$ is $\{xax^{-1}|x \text{ in } G\}$. So how does this related to a matrix? All the matrices similar to $A$(as the conjugate class of A)?

How could I use the condition $(A+1)^2(A-1)^4=0$? Since the dimension of A is 6, does it mean it should have two root $-1$, and four root $1$? And thus just consider all possible ways of Jordan blocks is OK?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is to classify up to similarity (base change) all linear operators on a $6$-dimensional space whose minimal polynomial divides $(X+1)^2(X-1)^4$. Nothing is specified about the field, but I will suppose it is not of characteristic$~2$ (in which case that polynomial would become $(X+1)^6$) which is the only relevant point here.

Since the minimal polynomial is split with roots $-1,1$ only, the operator admits a matrix in Jordan normal form, with Jordan blocs for $\lambda\in\{-1,1\}$ only. Moreover the divisibility condition says that Jordan blocs for $\lambda=-1$ cannot have size exceeding$~2$, and those for$\lambda=1$ cannot have size exceeding$~4$. You therefore get a fairly long list of possibilities, obtained as follows: write $6=k+l$ in all $7$ possible ways, and then for each combine all partitions of $k$ into parts of size at most$~2$ with all partition of$~l$ into parts of size at most$~4$.

The length of the list is$~44$: this is the coefficient of $X^6$ in $\frac1{(1-X)(1-X^2)}\times\frac1{(1-X)(1-X^2)(1-X^3)(1-X^4)}$ evaluated as power series.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I have a question. Do we need to restrict $k\le2$? I mean, if $k=3$(even though we partition it into, say, 1+2), does it mean we have three $\lambda=-1$ on diagonal? I think this is impossible, since the power of $(X+1)^2$ is only 2.

Comment: So I think essentially, my question is how (the power $r$ of $(X+1)^r$ in) minimal polynomial effect the Jordan block of $\lambda=-1$? (A). $r$ is the maximum size of the Jordan blocks of $\lambda=-1$. (B). $r$ is the sum of the sizes of the Jordan blocks of $\lambda=-1$. Which one is right? Thank you! In your answer, you assume (A) is right. I think (B) is right. Am I wrong(because I am dealing with characteristic poly instead of minimal poly)?

Comment: OK, so, I think you are right. So, this means, the polynomial $(X+1)^2(X-1)^4$ in the problem has nothing to do with the characteristic poly, but is related to(some multiple of) the minimal poly, right?

Comment: @Yes, a polynomial $P$ that annihilates the equation says something directly about the minimal polynomial (which must divide $P$) and only very indirectly about the characteristic polynomial (one just can say that all its roots must be among the roots of $P$). For instance $A=-I$ satisfies $(A+1)^2(A-1)^4=0$, and its characteristic polynomial is $(X+1)^6$, so $\{-I\}$  is one of the classes we must count for this question.